# Navigated to initial Route after change store state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am new in React Native. I tried to do a simple app including:

- Homepage
- List item

User page

I am using bottom navigator using createBottomTabNavigator which homepage is initial route
When I do some store state change using Redux dispatch then the app is navigated to the home page

Can you explain why and how to stop the navigation?
Thanks all.

Comment: add your code...

Comment: I detected my failure that the parent component of homepage took some props from the state which is changed in list item page, so whole page is re-rendered